# Xpos sell product that is not in store

Tags: magento-1.9, product

Is it possible to sell with the xpos app a product that is not in magento store?

If not is it possible to make in magento a product with a variable price?

We have some products that we dont want in shop we will click in xpos on a button and enter an price without any name for the product

Thanks for answers

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, I'd appreciate if you'd consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it...

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with the first question you raise, Magento has native support for custom product pricing levels. You have a bunch of different ways to do this: you can have a configurable product, with different prices for each child product; you can use product options to add to the price; and on the backend, you can specify a custom price for a product.

One of the things we've done for clients in the past is setting up custom products that accept a special price and the CSR can enter the name for the product. This allows "special-order" products, which I believe is similar to what you are talking about.